# Aspx Change page direction to Right to left

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a page which is LTR direction, and now I would like the page to work also with RTL direction. I care the most about the content in the middle of the page, that it would look nice.
Any ideas how to make it smooth without making a big mess?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the markup? Have you tried to change the direction? What happens? Where are you having problems?

Comment: I'm not having problems, I'm just trying to understand what's the best practice without making a mess.

Comment: Something as simple as **`<body dir="rtl">`** ?

Comment: True! I hope this is it. Do you guys think this will do it without any other changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about some content, then you could target only specific elements on the page for the direction change using : `<div  dir=rtl>...</div>` or `direction: rtl;` in CSS.